How to make bottom element animate using css when top element is removed from DOM?
Lets have 2 divs one is red in color and other is blue. Red div is on top and blue on bottom. Now on removing top element, bottom element shifts upwards. I basically want that when blue/bottom div shifts upwards there should be animation/transition which make it moves slowly to cover the gap.
edit: Also, the divs are not always of same height.
JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/gr13xoec/
HTML


var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var ele = document.getElementById('red');


setTimeout(()=> {
 parent.removeChild(ele);
}, 2000) 
.box{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;  
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
  animation: move 5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {top: 100%}
   100% {top: 0%}
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="red" class="box red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="box blue">  
  </div>
</div>




You can't do that with a transition or an animation. You would need to get the position of the element with JS and then animate it to the new (again, JS calculated) position. It's not a simple process.

if you have the chance to set the height to zero instead of removing the element from dom, you may still use the same css transition strategy and achieve the goal you are aiming to.

If the three targets above aren't enough, there are a few tens of thousands more here

Is this what your aiming for?


var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var ele = document.getElementById("red");

setTimeout(() => {
  parent.classList.add("mystyle");

}, 2000)

setTimeout(() => {
  parent.removeChild(ele);
}, 9000)
.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.mystyle .blue {
  transition: top 2s;
  top: 0px;
}

.mystyle #red {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
<div id="parent">
  <div id="red" class="box red">
  </div>

  <div class="box blue">
  </div>
</div>



We don't need the height because the disappearing (.red) div that took the height up is no longer taking up the height and is preceding the second (.blue) div in the DOM.
